# PostFix Config and PHP

Tags: postfix, email-server

I'm trying use the PHP mail function to send email on a server (the server is only suppose to send emails and not receive any emails) The PHP mail function returns that email has been sent, however the mail is not actually sent. In the mail.log, I see the following error.

```
Sep 13 14:32:32 www postfix/master[7851]: terminating on signal 15
Sep 13 14:32:32 www postfix/master[8018]: daemon started -- version 2.9.6, configuration /etc/postfix
Sep 13 14:32:35 www postfix/pickup[8024]: 2FE12E084: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Sep 13 14:32:35 www postfix/cleanup[8041]: 2FE12E084: message-id=<20140913183235.2FE12E084@www.mydomain.com>
Sep 13 14:32:35 www postfix/qmgr[8025]: 2FE12E084: from=<www-data@mydomain.com>, size=1019, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 13 14:32:35 www postfix/smtp[8043]: warning: relayhost configuration problem
Sep 13 14:32:35 www postfix/smtp[8043]: 2FE12E084: to=<myemail@hotmail.com>, relay=none, delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0, dsn=4.3.5, status=deferred (mail for mydomain.com loops back to myself)
```

Below is the PostFix configuration:

```
myhostname = www.mydomain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.localdomain, , localhost
relayhost = $mydomain
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
myorigin = $mydomain
inet_protocols = all
relay_domains = mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the needed information is provided by the error message `warning: relayhost configuration problem`

You can't use `$mydomain` as your relay host. You should enter a ip or fqdn to a server which should relay all your mails (or keep the relayhost setting empty if you have no relay).

Comment: I changed it to empty and everything is working! Thank you so much!

Comment: Nice to hear that everything is working. Please feel free to accept my answer as your solution. ;)